# Saving data to h5

Tags: python, numpy, h5py

I am trying to save data to **.h5** file. The data format is some thing like this:

```
[(1, array([[ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.]]), 64, 64), 
(2, array([[ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.]]), 64, 64),
(3, array([[ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.]]), 64, 64),
(4, array([[ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.]]), 64, 64)]
```

I am getting this error: 
`ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.`

Please help me to save the data to h5.

Code snippet:

```
import numpy as np
dataA = np.ones((1,4))
const1 = 64
const2 = 64
my_list = []

for i in range(1,5):
    data = (i,dataA,const1,const2)
    my_list.append(data)

#print my_list

#Saving to h5
import h5py
f = h5py.File('sample.h5','a')
f.create_dataset('data',data=my_list,dtype=np.float32)
```

Comment: from the error it sounds like the data you are trying to write into a single array element is a sequence.. you should check your my_list content and try debugging it manually

Comment: `h5py` can only store numpy arrays, not python lists. And it can't be object dtype either.  It can handle structured arrays. You may need to save your data as several arrays rather than one compound one.

Comment: Thanks for reply . Is there  any way that i can store my list to h5. or can i convert list to numpy array

Comment: Have you read the basic h5py docs?  The part about saving an array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I wrote in a comment, `h5py` saves arrays, not lists.  So with your call, it tries to convert your list into an array:

```
In [645]: alist
Out[645]: 
[(1, array([[ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.]]), 64, 64),
 (2, array([[ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.]]), 64, 64),
 (3, array([[ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.]]), 64, 64),
 (4, array([[ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.]]), 64, 64)]
In [646]: np.array(alist)
...
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

That step produces the error.  Now if I specify a object dtype I can turn it into an array, a (4,4) one containing integers and arrays.

```
In [647]: np.array(alist, dtype=object)
Out[647]: 
array([[1, array([[ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.]]), 64, 64],
       [2, array([[ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.]]), 64, 64],
       [3, array([[ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.]]), 64, 64],
       [4, array([[ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.]]), 64, 64]], dtype=object)
```

But `h5py` cannot save that kind of array.

I could make a structured array from that list with:

```
In [649]: np.array(alist, dtype='i,4i,i,i')
Out[649]: 
array([(1, [1, 1, 1, 1], 64, 64), (2, [1, 1, 1, 1], 64, 64),
       (3, [1, 1, 1, 1], 64, 64), (4, [1, 1, 1, 1], 64, 64)],
      dtype=[('f0', '<i4'), ('f1', '<i4', (4,)), ('f2', '<i4'), ('f3', '<i4')])
```

This happens to work because it is a list of tuples, a significant detail.  `h5py` can save that:

```
In [651]: arr = np.array(alist, dtype='i,4i,i,i')
In [652]: f.create_dataset('alist', data=arr)
Out[652]: <HDF5 dataset "alist": shape (4,), type "|V28">
```

and I can even read and convert it back into a list of tuples:

```
In [654]: f['alist'][:].tolist()
Out[654]: 
[(1, array([1, 1, 1, 1]), 64, 64),
 (2, array([1, 1, 1, 1]), 64, 64),
 (3, array([1, 1, 1, 1]), 64, 64),
 (4, array([1, 1, 1, 1]), 64, 64)]
```

though more often I'd access such an array be field name:

```
In [655]: f['alist']['f1']
Out[655]: 
array([[1, 1, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 1, 1]])
```

But I wonder whether you know enough `numpy` to be comfortable with structured arrays.  Is there a particular reason why you construct the list like this?  It's not particularly useful for `numpy` style calculations.

Another option is to keep the columns in separate arrays, and save those individually.